# Python: Search into list fail

Tags: python, list, search

Can anyone explain what is goin on in this code?

```
def some_function(value):
    my_list = [value, [True, "Some text"]]

    if True in my_list:
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "no"
```

---

```
>>> print(function(1))
yes

>>> print(function("1"))
no
```

If value = 1, I got "yes" and this behaviour is correct. But if value is some string, result is "no". I thought that should always be "yes". I use Python3.4

Comment: @Tichodroma: Title edit was wrong - question says _""value = 1, I got "yes" and this behaviour is correct"_, implying the issue with the question is not why `1 == True`

Comment: @Eric. Agreed. But the current title is wrong, too. The list has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: `True` isn't in `my_list`, it is however in `my_list[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that

```
1 == True
"1" != True
```

So it is the case that

```
[1, [True, "Some text"]]
```

contains `True`, while

```
["1", [True, "Some text"]]
```

does not.

**Edit:** It does not matter that the sublist contains `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Your list contains two items - `value`, and `[True, "Some text"]`.

When `value` is `1`, `value` is equal to `True`, so the result is `yes`

When `value` is `'1'`, neither of these two items are equal to `True`, so the result is `no`

---

It sounds like you're assuming that `x in list` should look in all sublists as well - that's not the case

Comment: Oh, I thouth that in list all elements:  _value, True and "some text"_ and in console sould be "yes" because _True_ in elements.

Comment: @rec99: Nope. `True in [1, [True, 3]]` is false, but `True in [1, True, 3]` is true